# Python size() and len() for list of list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list:

```
a = [[1, 0], 'apple', 5]
```

Why does `size(a[0])` work even though `a` isn't a `numpy array`?

I thought size worked only on arrays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size[a[0]]` shouldn't work, but `size(a[0])` should.  You can simply look at the source for `np.size`:

```
def size(a, axis=None):
    [docstring removed]

    if axis is None:
        try:
            return a.size
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).size
    else:
        try:
            return a.shape[axis]
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).shape[axis]
```

When you pass a list, `axis` stays at its default value of `None` and the function tries to get `a.size`.  Since that doesn't exist, it turns the list into an array using `asarray(a)` and gets the size that way.  In your case, it will make a 1-D numpy array of dtype `object`.

Comment: Wow. My first ever question posted on this forum and I actually got a really insightful answer. Thanks!